# Android AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE is not working

Tags: android

I'm executing following code inside my Activity to set the ringer mode and value:

```
void setRinger(int value) {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, value, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
}

void setSilent() {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
}

void setVibrate() {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
}
```

setRinger() sets ringer value and play sound as a confirmation.
setSilent() sets silent mode and show "toast" as a confirmation.
setVibrate() sets the vibrate mode but the phone is NOT vibrating as confirmation.

I'm using HTC Wildfire S (Android 2.3.5). When I change ringer volume using buttons on the phone the vibration is working fine.

What am I doing wrong? Any spacial privileges? I try to add android.permission.VIBRATE to the manifest - didn't help.

Manifest with permission:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".DroidUtilityActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

Logcat output (I cut off most logs) just to prove the code was called:

```
D/dalvikvm(13742): GC_CONCURRENT freed 279K, 47% free 2992K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+9ms
D/dalvikvm(11205): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 47% free 2862K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 153ms
D/AudioManager(13742): setStreamVolume(streamType:2, index:3, flags:4)
V/test    (13742): setringer
D/InputManagerService(  131): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40900198
D/VolumePanel(  131): prepare sound
D/VolumePanel(  131): prepare sound/system/media/audio/ui/Volume-1.mp3
D/VolumePanel(  131): prepare sound/system/media/audio/ui/Volume-2.mp3
...
E/AudioService(  131): [AudioHandler] syncSetIndex Call setStreamVolumeIndex isHeadsetPlugged(): true
D/StatusBarService(  219): updateIcon slot=volume index=15 viewIndex=9 old=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200c7 level=0 visible=false num=0 ) icon=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200c6 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
D/AudioManager(13742): setStreamVolume(streamType:2, index:0, flags:1)
V/test    (13742): setsilent
D/InputManagerService(  131): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40b235c8
D/AudioService(  131): [AudioHandler] persistVolumeForHeadset Name: volume_system_headset, mIndex_Headset: 0, mLastAudibleIndex_Headset: 7, current: true, lastAudible: true
D/AudioService(  131): [AudioHandler] persistVolumeForHeadset Name: volume_ring_headset, mIndex_Headset: 0, mLastAudibleIndex_Headset: 4, current: true, lastAudible: true
D/AudioService(  131): [AudioHandler] persistVolumeForHeadset Name: volume_ring_headset, mIndex_Headset: 0, mLastAudibleIndex_Headset: 4, current: true, lastAudible: true
D/AudioService(  131): [AudioHandler] persistVolumeForHeadset Name: volume_system_headset, mIndex_Headset: 0, mLastAudibleIndex_Headset: 7, current: true, lastAudible: true
D/StatusBarService(  219): updateIcon slot=volume index=15 viewIndex=9 old=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200c6 level=0 visible=true num=0 ) icon=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200c7 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
D/AudioManager(13742): setStreamVolume(streamType:2, index:0, flags:16)
V/test    (13742): setvibrate
D/InputManagerService(  131): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40c2d508
D/StatusBarPolicy(  219): onSignalStrengthsChanged
D/StatusBarService(  219): updateIcon slot=phone_signal index=20 viewIndex=13 old=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d0 level=0 visible=true num=0 ) icon=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d0 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
I/EventLogService(  273): Aggregate from 1326197648488 (log), 1326197648488 (data)
D/LocationManager(  131): _handleMessage: TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED
D/GpsLocationProvider(  131): [handleMessage] message :7
D/GpsLocationProvider(  131): [handleMessage] UPDATE_LOCATION
D/GpsLocationProvider(  131): handleUpdateLocation
D/LocationManager( 3422): _handleMessage: TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED
D/LocationManager(  327): _handleMessage: TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED
D/LocationManager( 6893): _handleMessage: TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED
D/LocationManager(  327): _handleMessage: TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED
```

Comment: that sounds correct for your manifest, did you already try to put log on those methods to see if they are ok? to see if the code is executed?

Comment: VIBRATE permission is to perform vibrating with help of code, i think we have give "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" permission because we are modifying audio setting for further details of permissions check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" didn't help.

Everything seems to be fine. The AudioManager logs following data in logCat as a result of my code:
setRinger(3) - logCat: setStreamValume(streamType:2, index:3, flags:4);
setSilent() - logCat: setStreamValume(streamType:2, index:0, flags:1);
setVibrate() - logCat: setStreamValume(streamType:2, index:0, flags:16);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you (using HTC Desire HD). In my case using two flags (AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE and AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI) at the same time resolve problem – phone vibrates and vibrate dialog appears. However, when I am using only AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE flag phone doesn’t vibrate. Below my code:

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
int currentStreamRing = manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,currentStreamRing,AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE+AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace by those code

```
void setRinger(int value) {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, value, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
Log.v("setringer");
}

void setSilent() {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
Log.v("setsilent");
}

void setVibrate() {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
Log.v("setvibrate");
}
```

To see of those methods are well called!
Then paste your logcat when you launch your app if you don't understand what is in trouble

Comment: I put the logcat output as you requested. Nothing new. I know that the code is running. As I wrote at the beginning - the ringer modes is set correctly and I got confirmation for first 2 methods. The only thing not working is "vibration" in setVibrate() method.

Comment: // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 
// Start immediately
// Vibrate for 200 milliseconds
// Sleep for 500 milliseconds
long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 500 };
 
// The "0" means to repeat the pattern starting at the beginning
// CUIDADO: If you start at the wrong index (e.g., 1) then your pattern will be off --
// You will vibrate for your pause times and pause for your vibrate times !
v.vibrate(pattern, 0);

Comment: This code runs the vibration manually. I was thinking about such solution. But this doesn't answer the question - why the vibration confirmation is not working? I would rather to find the answer and not to implement workaround, if it is not necessary. Thanks anyway!